# PCL remove points under a segmented table

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, eigen3

I want to remove all points under a recognized table. How should I do this?
I have the following functional code to segment/remove the table from a point cloud:

```
    std::cout << "(II) segmenting table plane ..." << std::endl;
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr segmented_scene(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers(new pcl::PointIndices());
    ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients(new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
    SACSegmentation<PointXYZ> segmentation;
    segmentation.setInputCloud(downsampledScene);
    segmentation.setModelType(pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
    segmentation.setMethodType(pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
    segmentation.setDistanceThreshold(threshold);
    segmentation.setOptimizeCoefficients(true);
    segmentation.setMaxIterations(1000);
    //PointIndices inlierIndices;
    segmentation.segment(*inliers, *coefficients);
    ExtractIndices<PointXYZ> extract;
    extract.setInputCloud(downsampledScene);
    extract.setIndices(inliers);
    extract.setNegative(true);
    extract.filter(*segmented_scene);
    //copyPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(*downsampledScene, inlierIndices, *segmented_scene);
    copyPointCloud(*segmented_scene, *outputCloud);
```

Or how can I set the origin of the coordinate system on the table to use a passthrough filter to filter all points under the table?
I tested this with the following code, but I think this is not correct:

```
    Eigen::Affine3f transform_1 = Eigen::Affine3f::Identity();
    cout << coefficients->values[0] << " " << coefficients->values[1] << " " << coefficients->values[2] << endl;
    transform_1.translation() << coefficients->values[0], coefficients->values[1], coefficients->values[2];
    transformPointCloud(*segmented_scene, *segmented_scene, transform_1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:

Create Eigen::Vector3d **n** of coefficients(0,1,2).
Calculate the angle between the Vector and the z-axis.
invert n, coefficients.value(3) and angle if angle > 0, because z filter limits [ setFilterLimits(FLT_MIN,FLT_MAX); ]
Create Eigen::Affine3d **t** (Eigen::Translation3d(n*coefficients.values(3)));
Calculate the **r** AngelAxisd(angle,axis)
Calculate the transformation **r** * **t**
transform the point Cloud
Use a passthrough filter and set the limits.
And then inverse transformation

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to create a convex hull around the planar points that you extracted, and project it down to create a prism below that convex hull, removing the points inside that prism. This is easily done with the Point Cloud Library using the [pcl::ExtractPolygonalPrismData](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.1/classpcl_1_1_extract_polygonal_prism_data.html) class.

A tutorial for using this class can be found [here](http://robotica.unileon.es/mediawiki/index.php/PCL/OpenNI_tutorial_5:_3D_object_recognition_%28pipeline%29#Segmentation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tested this tutorial, but i failed with the following error: '[pcl::ConvexHull::performReconstrution2D] ERROR: qhull was unable to compute a convex hull for the given point cloud (53493)! [pcl::ExtractPolygonalPrismData::segment] Not enough points (0) in the hull!'. My HeightLimits ist set to: 'prism.setHeightLimits(0.0f, 500.0f);' because I have a PointClound in mm. (eg.: -2906.6528 -3386.3918 8212). The Object on the table has a height of ca. 10 cm.

Comment: Seems like it thinks there are no points in the convex hull (i.e. the table). Not sure why. Anyway, you have a solution.

Comment: Is it me or is the link to the tutorial dead?

Comment: If so, only recently. Anyway, you can use the internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20141013032334/http://robotica.unileon.es/mediawiki/index.php/PCL/OpenNI_tutorial_5:_3D_object_recognition_%28pipeline%29